# insert into interval partition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I'm using oracle 11g.

in my db, i have a table with rqnge interval, which the interval is by 1 for month.

when i execute an insert-select into the table it's go into endless loop.

but i execute the same insert select into other partition table - not interval one, it's pass great.

I did a trace on a test simple insert and that what i got:

```
insert into "DELIVERY_BY_MONTH_PART" (SAVE_MNTH)  
values
(trunc (to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'month'))


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      1.40       5.37          0        228          23167           1
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        2      1.40       5.37          0        228      23167           1

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 21300  

Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
  0  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL  DELIVERY_BY_MONTH_PART (cr=153359 pr=0 pw=0 time=5899030 us)


Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  control file sequential read                  880        0.00          0.09
  db file sequential read                        88        0.00          0.00
  Disk file operations I/O                      132        0.14          0.27
  Data file init write                           44        0.00          0.00
  db file single write                           44        0.00          0.00
  control file parallel write                   132        0.00          0.02
  rdbms ipc reply                                44        0.00          0.06
  log file sync                                   1        0.00          0.00
  SQL*Net message to client                       1        0.00          0.00
  SQL*Net message from client                     1       15.24         15.24
********************************************************************************
```

someone??

thanks.

Comment: The issue concerns `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, but you have shown a trace for `INSERT ...VALUES` command. It's hard to give any advice for X looking at Y.

Comment: yeah. but my goal is to show that even with simple insert it's still like that.